# Running bitcoin-qt as client

Tags: linux, bitcoin-qt-setup

I want to configure bitcoin-qt to work as a 'client' for parallel bitcoind server (the same way as bitcoin-cli), but I don't see any relevant configuration options. In my PC bitcoind has folowing configuration: data directory is /var/lib/bitcoind, it is run as 'bitcoin:bitcoin' user (with the same data permissions in /var/lib/bitcoind). Running bitcoin-qt from main desktop user does not work because bitcoin data directory permission differs, running gui app from 'bitcoin' user also does not work.

I want to work sometimes with bitcoind, sometimes with bitcoin-qt. The problem with bitcoin-qt is that there are no separate bitcoind/bitcoin-cli programs. In case of bitcoind I can preserve normal 'bitcoin:bitcoin' data directory permissions and connect to bitcoind with bitcoin-cli. Bitcoin-qt documentation mentions 'rpc_connect' options, but they seem to apply to possible bitcoin-qt clients, not bitcoin-qt acting as a client to bitcoind.

Curently I see the only way to archive what I want: change data directory permissions to main user (who starts bitcoin-qt). But this method is hackish because it requres modification of systemd bitcoind.service file, data permission changes, etc, which I would like to avoid. Perhaps I am missing some way to configure bitcoin-qt properly?

Comment: I have found solution which does not require configuring bitcoin-qt (it is not possible according to the answer below) and which still achives what I want. It appears my assumption about impossibility of running GUI app in linux from another (bitcoin) user was wrong: it is possible to do with 'xhost si:localuser:bitcoin' command (allows 'bitcoin' user to access linux graphical server). This method allows to run bitcoin-qt via 'sudo -u bitcoin bitcoin-qt -conf...' on data directory having 'bitcoin' permissions. However, this information belongs to linux stackexchange rather than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s simply no support for using the Bitcoin-QT application as a RPC client, it needs far more access to state than is provided by that interface to operate.

There’s no real reason to try to separate users like that either way, if the desktop user has access to RPC, what is the difference to it just running the daemon itself? Assuming that loss of the bitcoin wallet is game over, it doesn’t change much.

Comment: I disagree with the part "There’s no real reason ..." because it does not address my issue. It was not about loss of wallet, or separating users. I want to run both bitcoind and bitcon-qt (not in parallel) on the same data directory. It is doable if default data access permission are changed to the user running bitcoin-qt, but this method is somewhat 'dirty' - that's why I was asking whether it is doable with bitcoin-qt configuration. Still, I marked the reply as answer because it addresses the question about bitcoin-qt configuration (that it is not possible).